# How is Composure defined?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

In the V5 Playtest rules (pg 22, 24, and 38) a Composure stat is mentioned several times, but I can't find a description of the stat or its levels.

The character sheet provided at the end of the document shows that it can vary between 1 and 5 dots and has both a Permanent and Temporary rating (similar to Willpower). Am I missing any mention of how the stat is calculated or where it is defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't defined super clearly in terms of how it relates to your character but how it works and how it works in the game is defined at the bottom of page 22.

Essentially composure is your ability to resist compulsions that result from hunger and works similarly to fate points from fate. When one of your rolls triggers a compulsion you can either accept the compulsion and act it out (possibly gaining a point of composure from the storyteller)

> Acting  out the  compulsion rewards  you  with a  point  of  Composure,  at the  Storytellers  discretion.

or refuse it by spending a point of composure.

> The only way to  avoid  this consequence  is to  spend Composure,  allowing you  to  quash  the  unwanted  impulse,  at least  temporarily.

Also the reason it has temporary values is on page 22 as well.

> Just  like  Willpower, Composure  is a spendable  trait,  with  a current  and  a maximum  value.

Comment: Thanks, I literally don't know how I missed that part on how to regain Composure (it came up during my playtest).